# Fill Dropdownlist countries based on User login in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to fill `dropdownlist` `countries` based on `User login` into my application. If user is not logged on then the default country will be displayed. Please help me and guide me how to fill dropdown based on user logon country. Any help is highly appreciated.

[AspUsers table -- When user register, all the information goes to this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaBu6.png)

[image: Country table]

My `LeadingClass` data Model

```
 public int? Type { get; set; }   
   public string Country { get; set; }
```

My `LeadingFilterVM` View Model

```
 public int? Type { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeList { get; set; }    
  public string Country { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountriesList { get; set; }
 public IPagedList<LeadingClass> Leadings { get; set; }
```

My `LeadingDatabaseHandle`

```
public List<LeadingClass> LeadingBasedonFilter(int? Type, string Country = "")
        {
            clsUtilities clsUtilities = new clsUtilities();
            DataSet ds;
            List<LeadingClass> leadingClass = new List<LeadingClass>();
            string sSQL;
            SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[3];
            sSQL = "exec GetLeeading @Type,@country";
            prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@Type", SqlDbType.Int);
            prms[0].Value = Sire;
            prms[1] = new SqlParameter("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            prms[1].Value = Country;
            ds = clsUtilities.CreateCommandwithParams(sSQL, prms);
            DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                leadingClass.Add(
                    new LeadingClass
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),
                        Name= Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]),

                    }
                    );
            }

            return leadingClass;
        }
```

My `Home` Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Leading(int? type, string country,int? pageNumber)
        {

            LeadingDatabaseHandle leadingDatabaseHandle = new LeadingDatabaseHandle();
           IEnumerable<LeadingClass> data;

            if (type!=null)
            {

                data = leadingDatabaseHandle.LeadingBasedonFilter(type.Value, country);
            }
            else
            {
               data = leadingDatabaseHandle.LeadingSiresAll();
            }
            LeadingFilterVM model = new LeadingFilterVM
            {
                Type = type,
                Country = country,

                TypeList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "General", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Advance", Value = "2" },
            },
                CountriesList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
              new SelectListItem {Value = "NZ", Text="New Zealand" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "AUS", Text = "Australia" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "FR", Text = "France" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "GB", Text = "Great Britain" },

            },


               Leadings = data.ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10)

            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

My `Leading` View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Leading", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
            {
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Leadings.FirstOrDefault().Type)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, Model.TypeList, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

            <div class=" col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Country)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountriesList, new { @class = "form-control"})
            </div>



            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _If user is not logged on then the default country will be displayed_? What is the 'default country'? And why are you hard-coding in the countries - they need to be generated based on a `Countries` table (that has a relationship with your `Users` table

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Good morning! the default country will be New Zealand if user has not logged on. If user is from Australia then it should show Australia. The reason why i hard coded those part is that there are more than 100 countries in the database and we do not want all of those data. so I hard coded that part. Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: You should not be hard coding them. You need to get them from the database. And the `CountryId` in the `Users` table` is an `int` so your option values need to be the same (not the `CountryCode`). And you defeating the benefits of server side paging by getting all the filtered records, converting them to a `DataSet` and then converting them to a collection of `LeadingClass` (didn't we discuss that in a previous question?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes we discussed about this last time. But they are using Dataset asked me to do the same. So I am just following their patterns. When user register their profile, that time, the country dropdownlist is getting Country from Country table. But now on the page, it should reflect based on user log on.

Comment: Absolutely crazy to be using a `DataSet` and degrading performance like that. But you need to populate the `SelectList` from the database and set the `Value` property of each `SelectListItem` to the `CountryId` property. Then you need to make it `public int? Country { get; set; }` in your `LeadingFilterVM` and set that property in the GET method based on the current `User` (and if the user is not logged in, then don't set it and the first option will be selected)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I will really appreciate, if you can provide a sample solution for this. I understand that it will be bit hard to find time from your busy schedule. But please help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161409/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-raj).